# Can I to specify the width of a table but keeping the height and font size?

Tags: latex

I want the tables of my report have the same width as the text column but keeping the height according to its content. \rezisebox is not what I need because it rezise the width and the height and change the font size. There's a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more what you're trying to do. How many columns does the table have? As a first guess, the tabularx package may help, but we really need more detail in order better to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/tabularx.html):

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ ...format... }
    ...
    contents
    ...
\end{tabularx}
```